# R import .data file extension

Tags: r, data-import

Hi I'm trying to import data from the URL:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data but it always imports it as single line. I split the data by "\t" but it still not working. My R code;

```
    bostonHousing <- read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data",
 col.names= c("CRIM","ZN","INDUS","CHAS","NOX","RM","AGE","DIS","RAD","TAX","PTRATIO","B","LSTAT","MEDV"),
                                  dec=",",sep = "\t")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file isn't tab-separated, it's whitespace-separated.  By default, `read.table` assumes columns are separated by one or more whitespace characters (tab *or* space). Specifying tab-delimiters (or using `read.delim()`) is only really necessary when columns are tab-delimited *and* the data columns may contain embedded spaces ...

```
url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data"
bostonHousing <- read.table(url)
```

seems to work fine (`dec=","` is also a bad idea)